# Entity Framework under the hood

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have some legacy code that uses Entity Framework.

When I debug the code I can see that EF DbContext contains the whole table. It was passed by OData to the frontend, and then angular processed it.

So I tried to search, is it possible to get only a single record by EF?

Everywhere I see the `SingleOrDefault` method, or other IQueryable, but as I understood, these are parts of the `collections`.

Microsoft says: Sometimes the value of default(TSource) is not the default value that you want to use if the **collection** contains no elements.

Does that mean EF always get all the data from the table and I can use them later?

Or is there a way to force inner query to get only one, and only one row?

We are using postgresql.

Comment: Have you tried `.Take(1)`, or do I misunderstand you?

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  Yes, you can call `Single()` and other methods wherever you want.

Comment: and will be the inner query `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 23` ?

Comment: @vaso123 The query inner to what, and when you do what?  Your question makes no sense.

Comment: I mean, when I checked the query, it always query the whole table, and then I can get the first, single, etc... from the whole collection. Is it possible to force somehow the EF to get only one row, not one entity from collection?

Comment: `default(someClass)` will always be `null`; `default(someSimpleType)` will either be zero (numeric) or false (boolean). I think this is implementation specific, though.

Comment: Is the question whether EF always `SELECT`s the whole table even if you want only one row?

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih yes, sorry for my bad english

Comment: @vaso123: EF will always issue queries that only select the rows you need, depending on how you write your query (and as long as you don't call `AsEnumerable()` first).  Learn about LINQ to EF.

Comment: @vaso123 No, it does not, if you're doing it right. Otherwise that would be catastrophical.

Comment: EF is meant to create a query in the SQL dialect of the connected RDBMS which is the functional equivalent to the LINQ query. So that the entire table is normally not even transmitted from db to server-side. If you assign the whole entity instance to some web control, that will be all rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Entity Framework, you can use LINQ to run queries and get single records or limited sets. However, in your .NET project the controller should be parsing OData query parameters and filtering the dataset before returning results to the client application. Please check your Controller code against [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint) to see if you might be missing something.

If you are somehow bypassing the built-in OData framework, what might help is understanding which queries execute immediately vs which ones are deferred. See [this list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/classification-of-standard-query-operators-by-manner-of-execution) to understand exactly which operations will force a trip to the database and try to hold off on anything with immediate execution until as late as possible.

Comment: I think this was what I need. I just need a day while I am checking. If `public SingleResult<Product> Get([FromODataUri] int key)` works, I will accept it. Upvote.

Comment: @vaso123 thanks, don't forget to add the ```[EnableQuery]``` decorator so that ASP.Net can automagically parse the OData query params

Comment: Thank for the links.

Answer (score 1):

No, EF will not SELECT the entire table into memory if you use it *correctly*. By correctly; I mean:

```
context.Table.First();
```

Will translate into a SQL query that only returns one row, that will then map to an object to be returned to the calling code. This is because the above code uses LINQ-to-Entities. If you did something like this instead:

```
context.Table.ToList().First();
```

Then the entire table is selected to make the `ToList` work, and LINQ-to-Objects handles the `First`. So as long as you do your queries with lazy enumeration (not realizing the result ahead of time), you'll be fine.

Comment: If you are using ASP.NET MVC OData this is a bit confusing as your controller will return the base query, and the URI passed by the client will be composed with the query you return from your controller before it is translated to SQL and executed.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Performance is the neck of bottle for our enterprise project. I am new to C# and ASP.NET and we have time to explore our code. As I sad, we are using postgre. What do you recommend? Should we write our own DB layer (like `Db.getRow(sqlCmd)`), what holds `SELECT field1, field2 FROM users WHERE id = 242` (what is gives back 1 row for us) or is it possible with EF? And drop EF and OData

Comment: "What do you recommend?"  Learn how to use EF and OData effectively.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Ok, thank you for you help. Tomorrow I will check it. If `public SingleResult<Product> Get([FromODataUri] int key)` works as I expect, I will dig it deeper.